# How can I get list of adapter types in VMWare by vSphere client API

Tags: java, vsphere, esxi

I want to create a **virtual machine on ESXi 6.0** by configured adapter type.
Basically, these 3 (E1000, Vmxnet2, VMXNET3) are listing while creating the virtual machine, but I can't find any API in java.
I am importing below packages:

```
import com.vmware.vim25.VirtualEthernetCard;
import com.vmware.vim25.VirtualEthernetCardNetworkBackingInfo;
import com.vmware.vim25.VirtualHardware;
import com.vmware.vim25.VirtualMachineConfigInfo;
import com.vmware.vim25.VirtualMachineConfigSpec;
import com.vmware.vim25.VirtualMachineNetworkInfo; 



 ArrayList<HostSystem> hosts = OperationHelper.GetAllHostReferene();
 ArrayList<String> networkNames = new ArrayList<String>();
 Network[] nws = null;
    for(HostSystem host : hosts) {
        Datastore[] dts = host.getDatastores();
        for(Datastore d : dts){
            if(d.getName().equals(m_datastore)) {
                log.info("Found host for datastore");
                nws = host.getNetworks();
              for(Network n : nws){
                 networkNames.add(n.getName());                 
              }
           }
       }
   }
```

I get Network interface card list by above code. But I am not able to get adapter types.
Please help out.

Answer (score 1):

Each VM network adapter inherits from [VirtualEthernetCard](https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere#https%3A%2F%2Fvdc-repo.vmware.com%2Fvmwb-repository%2Fdcr-public%2F6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22%2Ffa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc%2Fdoc%2Fvim.vm.device.VirtualEthernetCard.html). For example:

[VirtualEthernetCard](https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere#https%3A%2F%2Fvdc-repo.vmware.com%2Fvmwb-repository%2Fdcr-public%2F6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22%2Ffa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc%2Fdoc%2Fvim.vm.device.VirtualEthernetCard.html) <|-- [VirtualVmxnet](https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere#https%3A%2F%2Fvdc-repo.vmware.com%2Fvmwb-repository%2Fdcr-public%2F6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22%2Ffa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc%2Fdoc%2Fvim.vm.device.VirtualVmxnet.html) <|-- [VirtualVmxnet3](https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere#https%3A%2F%2Fvdc-repo.vmware.com%2Fvmwb-repository%2Fdcr-public%2F6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22%2Ffa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc%2Fdoc%2Fvim.vm.device.VirtualVmxnet3.html) <|-- [VirtualVmxnet3Vrdma](https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere#https%3A%2F%2Fvdc-repo.vmware.com%2Fvmwb-repository%2Fdcr-public%2F6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22%2Ffa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc%2Fdoc%2Fvim.vm.device.VirtualVmxnet3Vrdma.html)

You should be passing instances of these classes to the list of VM devices when calling ReconfigureVM().